# Send data to specific client using UDP

Tags: python, network-programming, udp, fastapi

I am making a gateway server which sends and receive data between devices and a backend. I have to use UDP to communicate with the devices because that is an implemented technology. The devices have a fixed type of message that I cannot modify. My server is working with a public IP.

I would like to know if I can send data to a specific device, located in other network, using UDP without having a socket created. I only know the public IP of the network and the device's MAC.
The first approach was receive data through UDP, saving this data in REDIS and then using the devices data in REDIS as a JSON (MAC, local IP address, gateway address, etc). I know Redis is not persistent, but in this case could work for me.

The problem appeared when I wanted to  send data to a specific client. I think I could save the socket in a dictionary, for example, after receiving the data. I could do this in the Twisted module, for example.

It is a way to share the sockets dictionary between the two modules or it is better to do all the tasks in the same module? As far as I know, if I serialize the socket object, saving it in Redis an then deserializing again, I would lose the socket.

## **EDIT**

I could parse the clients data and save it in REDIS, so I know the address of the decives. I could test sending UDP data to the device and it responds. The problem appears when I want to attend for a request and then send UDP data to the device. I have this:

```
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import socket
import utils
from Server import Server
from ServerCommands import ServerCommands as sc

#-------------------------
eventHandler = Server()

async def send_udp_message_async(udp_socket, add , message: bytes):
    
    try:
        bytes_sent = udp_socket.sendto(message, add)
        print("MENSAJE ENVIADO ASYNC")
        return bytes_sent
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error al enviar el mensaje UDP:", str(e))
    finally:
        udp_socket.close()

async def receive_response(udp_socket, desired_response, timeout):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print("ingresa receive response")
# 1. Define data type
class Msg(BaseModel):
    msg: str
    mac: str
    add: tuple[str, int] = []
    id: int

# 2. Define an API object
app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    global UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT
    UDP_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
    UDP_PORT = 5002
@app.post("/send-udp/")
async def send_udp_message(inp: Msg):
    try:
        udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        udp_socket.setblocking(False)
        cmd_send = eventHandler.comandos.Ingreso()
        print(f"cmd_send: {cmd_send.hex()}")
        socket_device = await utils.check_placa(inp.mac, inp.add, inp.id)
        print(f"socket_device: {socket_device}, {type(socket_device)}")
        bytes_sent = await send_udp_message_async(udp_socket, socket_device, cmd_send)
        print("Tarea asincrona para enviar UDP iniciada")
        return {"message": f"Tarea asincrona de envío UDP iniciada a {socket_device}", "response": bytes_sent}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

#
if __name__=="__main__": 
    uvicorn.run('main_prueba:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, reload=True)
```

I have tested the communication between server and device and I received a valid response (after the reception of the data, de device activated a relay). Here's my test code, the device responds no matter the network it is:

```
import socket
from ServerCommands import ServerCommands as sc

SC = sc()
# Datos del cliente
cliente_ip = '181.45.185.233'  # Reemplaza con la dirección IP pública del cliente
cliente_puerto = 5002  # Reemplaza con el puerto del cliente

# Crear un socket UDP
udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
puerto_local = 5002  # Puerto local en el servidor
udp_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', puerto_local))

mensaje = SC.Ingreso()

try:
    # Enviar el mensaje al cliente
    udp_socket.sendto(mensaje, (cliente_ip, cliente_puerto))
    print('Mensaje enviado exitosamente al cliente.')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error al enviar el mensaje: {str(e)}')

finally:
    udp_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

> I only know the public IP of the network and the device's MAC

The MAC does not help at all since it only works as address inside the same local network.

The public IP by itself does not help as long as there is no mapping done by the router at this public IP and port to a specific internal IP address and port. Without such a mapping the router does not know where it should forward the data it has received and will therefore simply discard it.

Such a mapping might be a port forwarding added explicitly to the router. It might be some forwarding added by UPnP. The easiest way is probably that the internal program sends some data to the outside application, since this creates for some time a state in the router for the response data. But none of these can be done by the external program - it always needs help from inside.

Comment: I can receive data and associate that with a device. I could save the socket object created after receiving the data. I am having troubles finding a solution for make an API (currently, I am using FastAPI but I could change the framework) that responds to queries and sends specific messages to the devices **and simultaneously** attends to certain type of data sent by the same devices(like in a loop, to monitor them). Could you give me an advice to resolve this issue? It would be good if I could fit these tasks in one module.

Comment: @agustinlezcano: Data associated with the device are irrelevant here - they don't provide connectivity from outside to a device inside an internal network. Saved sockets objects by themselves don't help either, but if there is still an established connection with the socket you can simply send data on the socket to the internal peer. If you want to serve an API in the server and simultaneously do also other things just use threads or multiple processes.